# Mocking a TLS/SSL endpoint with manually set versions & ciphersuites

Tags: ssl, encryption, mocking

I have a client application that consumes a number of web services through SSL/TLS-Tunnels. I am trying to test handling and support for specific SSL/TLS versions and possible fallbacks.

Is there a lightweight tool which lets me set up a secure endpoint for which I can set the supported versions and ciphersuites manually (in a config file for example). I have been testing the WS functionality in SoapUI, but it does not offer to set the versions or ciphersuites for accepted SSL/TLS connections, therefore I am trying to test the tunnel by itself with another tool.

e.g. 
my client is set to TLS 1.0 with ONLY [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
mock server accepts only TLS 1.1 and higher
expected result: handshake failure

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: the most practical way I found was to setup a jboss-instance and configure it to support different TLS versions etc for different test cases. As the ssl handshake takes place way before any data (request/response) is sent, you do not even need a real or mock response. A simple helloWorld will do the trick.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Mock Server](http://www.mock-server.com/). It is basic Java and you should be able to adapt it to your setup needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used openssl's s_server for this purpose with good results:

openssl s_server -accept 443 -WWW -cipher AES128-SHA -tls1_1

This will serve files from the current directory using the AES128-SHA cipher suite (use 'openssl ciphers' for a full list) and restricted to TLS v1.1.  You can choose -tls1_0 or -tls1_2 for other versions.  You'll need to put your PEM format certificate and private key in server.pem or use the options (-cert -key -certform -keyform) for other files and formats.